# "Specified method is not supported" in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, exception

This is my entity class:

```
public partial class NerdDinnerEntities : ObjectContext
{
    public NerdDinnerEntities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString, "NerdDinnerEntities")
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectContext oc = new ObjectContext(connectionString);

           oc.Connection.ChangeDatabase("NERDDINNER1");
           oc.AcceptAllChanges();
            this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            OnContextCreated();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }

    partial void OnContextCreated();

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectSet<Dinner> Dinners
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_Dinners == null))
            {
                _Dinners = base.CreateObjectSet<Dinner>("Dinners");
            }
            return _Dinners;
        }
    }
    private ObjectSet<Dinner> _Dinners;

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectSet<RSVP> RSVPs
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_RSVPs == null))
            {
                _RSVPs = base.CreateObjectSet<RSVP>("RSVPs");
            }
            return _RSVPs;
        }
    }

    private ObjectSet<RSVP> _RSVPs;

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_sysdiagrams == null))
            {
                _sysdiagrams = base.CreateObjectSet<sysdiagram>("sysdiagrams");
            }
            return _sysdiagrams;
        }
    }

    private ObjectSet<sysdiagram> _sysdiagrams;

    /// <summary>
    /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the Dinners EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
    /// </summary>
    public void AddToDinners(Dinner dinner)
    {
        base.AddObject("Dinners", dinner);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the RSVPs EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
    /// </summary>
    public void AddToRSVPs(RSVP rSVP)
    {
        base.AddObject("RSVPs", rSVP);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the sysdiagrams EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
    /// </summary>
    public void AddTosysdiagrams(sysdiagram sysdiagram)
    {
        base.AddObject("sysdiagrams", sysdiagram);
    }
}
```

and these is my web.config file as

```
<add name="NerdDinnerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.NerdDinner.csdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.ssdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=@;Database=NERDDINNER;User ID=@;Password=@@@;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClients" />
```

and i am getting error:

> Specified method is not supported

in this line:

```
oc.Connection.ChangeDatabase("NERDDINNER1");
```

Comment: The code in your constructor looks very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the docs at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.changedatabase.aspx) you will see that the method literally is not supported. It must be a placeholder for future improvements or something.

To expand for those who do want to change the database at runtime:

1.Create an entry in your settings to use in-place of the default in the app.config. Pull out the specifics, like Username, password, catalog name (database name), server etc into other settings entries.

```
<Setting Name="EntityConnectionString2" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
  <Value Profile="(Default)">metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source={0};initial catalog={1};persist security info=True;user id={2};password={3};encrypt=True;trustservercertificate=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework"</Value>
</Setting>
```

*Please note the {0}..{3} entries & that this connection string is not the whole configuration/connectionStrings/add entry in the app.config*

2.Use one of the overloaded constructors for the EF Database that accepts a connection string.

```
var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;  
string constring = string.Format(settings.EntityConnectionString2, settings.Server, settings.Database, settings.User, settings.Password);
NerdDinnerEntities db = new NerdDinnerEntities (constring);
```

3.To change at runtime you can create a different object in the same manner with a different catalog name, or dispose and recreate the db object with a different catalog name.

Comment: is not possible to change the current database while it is open?

Comment: i have a dough that where to add that settings tag

Comment: You can add settings in two ways, I have shown the XML that gets created in the app.config, but the best way to add it is in the project properties -> Settings

Comment: can i add  it where the instance of NerdDinnerEntities  is called

Comment: @GowthamanSS Please reread the 3 points. StackOverflow cannot be used like a forum unfortunately. The goal is to create a customizable connection string so you can use different databases when necessary. In your file at pastie.org, you are using the ConfigurationManager. Settings are accessed by following point 2. You cant use the connection string from the configuration in the EF constructor. Compare point 1 connection string and the connection string in the configuration that you are loading.

Answer (score 0):

ChangeDatabase method of EntityConnection is not supported (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.changedatabase.aspx)

If you want to use your data context with another database, create another connection string and create data context instance using new connection string

Comment: how to create another connection string with data context instance ...can u guide me by sending some links

Comment: Duplicate connection string in web.config, change its name and change Database=NERDDINNER to something else in its value

Comment: means need to add new config string as <add name="NerdDinnerEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.NerdDinner.csdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.ssdl|res://*/Models.NerdDinner.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=@;Database=NERDDINNER1;User ID=@;Password=@@@;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClients" />

Comment: Change the name of connection string (name attribute) to avoid name duplication

Comment: ya k changed attribute name from NerdDinnerEntities to NerdDinnerEntities1 den how can i choose particular database in coding

Comment: @GowthamanSS please see my updated answer to address this last question